# Guava SortedSetMultimap doesn't put unordered values

Tags: java, guava, multimap

I want to create a TreeMultimap, but only the first value is added as a value. Here's my code:

```
SortedSetMultimap<Double, String> sorted = TreeMultimap.create(
    (o1, o2) -> o2.compareTo(o1), 
    (o1, o2) -> 0
);

allSuperSkuRepository.getAllSkuTitles().forEach(v -> {
    String sku = v.getSkuTitle().split(" - ")[0];
    Double lev = (double) levensteinDistance.getDistance(in, sku);
    if (lev.compareTo(0.3) > 0) lev = .5; // just for testing
    if (lev.compareTo(0.49) > 0) {
        log.debug(lev);
        log.debug(sku);
        sorted.put(lev, sku);
    }
});
log.debug(sorted); // {0.5=[s0104]}
```

As commented in the code, `log.debug(sorted)` only yields {0.5=[s0104]}, however the expected result would be `{0.5=[s0104, msr01, msr01-set]}`.

The `log.debug(lev), log.debug(sku)` are outputting the expected values.

What do I need to change in order to get all values for a key in my Multimap?

I'm using guava 19.

---

Important to note:

If I rewrite the comparator to

```
SortedSetMultimap<Double, String> sorted = TreeMultimap.create(
    (o1, o2) -> o2.compareTo(o1), 
    (o1, o2) -> o2.compareTo(o1)
);
```

all the values are actually added, but I don't want the values to be ordered in any way - they should appear in order of insertion.

Comment: Because I want the keys to be ordered @RC.. Sorry, thought that would be clear because of the way I `create()` the Multimap

Comment: my bad, I misunderstood. The problem with the comparator that returns 0 is that all values are considered == that might be the issue. Try using Ordering.natural()

Comment: @RC. well that still orders the values. But I found a hack as a solution.

Comment: @Michael you want `MultimapBuilder.treeKeys().linkedHashSetValues().build()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value comparator that you pass to the `TreeMultimap` factory says that all values are equal:

```
(o1, o2) -> 0
```

Hence, only the first one is retained. As the [documentation](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/index.html?com/google/common/collect/TreeMultimap.html) says (emphasis mine):

> Implementation of Multimap whose keys **and values** are ordered by their natural ordering or by supplied comparators. **In all cases, this implementation uses `Comparable.compareTo(T)` or `Comparator.compare(T, T)` instead of `Object.equals(java.lang.Object)` to determine equivalence of instances.**

What you really want is a custom `Multimap`, since none of the [predefined combinations](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#implementations-1) matches your use case:

```
SetMultimap<Double, String> sorted = Multimaps.newSetMultimap(
    new TreeMap<>(),
    LinkedHashSet::new);
```

The `TreeMap` will make sure the keys are sorted (using their natural ordering), and the `LinkedHashSet` for each collection of values will simply retain the insertion order while deduplicating the values.

If you don't have duplicate values, just use an `ArrayList` instead:

```
Multimap<Double, String> sorted = Multimaps.newMultimap(
    new TreeMap<>(),
    ArrayList::new);
```

---

**Update:** Louis Wasserman appropriately suggested in a comment using the `MultimapBuilder` fluent API instead to create the `Multimap` to specs:

```
Multimap<Double, String> sorted = MultimapBuilder.treeKeys().linkedHashSetValues().build();
```

or

```
Multimap<Double, String> sorted = MultimapBuilder.treeKeys().arrayListValues().build();
```

Comment: Are you looking for MultimapBuilder.treeKeys().arrayListValues().build()?

Comment: @LouisWasserman Or .linkedHashSetValues(), depending on OP's exact use case. Yes, apparently I am, I'll update the answer, thanks.